# not able to get the data and display on web using php

Tags: php, mysql

`$totDays = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$_REQUEST['month'],$_REQUEST['year']);
    $attData = $commonObj->getAttendanceData($_REQUEST['month'],$_REQUEST['year']);`
  `        
            
                
                    Student Name

```
            <?php foreach($attData as $attk=>$attv){
                $punchin = $commonObj->getTimeOfDate($attData[$attk]['punchin']);
                        $punchout = $commonObj->getTimeOfDate($attData[$attk]['punchout']);
                        $nam=$attv['name'];
                ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="danger">
                    <?php echo $nam;?>
                </th>
                <?php for($i=1;$i<=$totDays;$i++){?>

                    <?php if($commonObj->getDayOfDate($attData[$attk]['punch_time']) == $i){

                        echo "<td class='success' id='att_$i'>".$punchin.'-'.$punchout;?>
                        <table class="table table-responsive"style="display: none; position:relative;min-width:100px;max-width:200px; margin-top: -40px;" id="<?php echo "det_att_".$i;?>">
                            <tr>
                            <td>Time:</td>
                            <td><?php echo "p"?>
                            </td></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>UID:</td>
                                <td><?php echo $attData[$attk]['rfid_uid'];?></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <?php
                        }else {echo "<td class='info'>#na";}?>
                </td>
                <?php }?>
            </tr>
            <?php }?>
        </tr>
    </table>`
```

this is the code for displaying on the web for viewing attendance ..
and here is the code for database part for getting attendance...

```
public function getAttendanceData($month,$year){
    if(!is_numeric($month) || $month>12 || $month<1){
        $this->setErrorMsg("Please Select valid month!");
        header("location:viewAttendance.php");
        exit;
    }
    $retData = array();
    $fullDate = $year."-".$month;
    //print_r($_SESSION);
    if($_SESSION['user_type']==1){
          $sql = "
SELECT t1.*
     , t2.rfid_uid
     , punch_time as punchin
     , t2.name 
  FROM tbl_attendance as t1 
 right 
  join tbl_users as t2 
    on t1.rfid_uid = t2.rfid_uid 
 WHERE YEAR(punch_time) = $year 
   AND MONTH(punch_time) = $month  
   and t2.rfid_uid ='".$_SESSION['rfid_uid']."'
";
        $retData = $this->getData($sql);
    }else if($_SESSION['user_type'] == 2){
        $sql = "SELECT t1.*,t2.rfid_uid,punch_time as punchin,t2.name FROM tbl_attendance as t1 right join tbl_users as t2 on t1.rfid_uid=t2.rfid_uid WHERE YEAR(punch_time) = $year AND MONTH(punch_time) = $month group by t2.rfid_uid";
        $retData = $this->getData($sql);

    }
    return $retData;
}
```

[web viewing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boBuG.png)[database table for attendance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNMwZ.png)[user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klW4U.png)
the attendance is recorded in the database but is not shown on the web..please help

Comment: What is `getData` and why doesn't it support placeholder values?

Comment: public function getData($sql){
  $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
  $data = array();
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $data[] = $row;
          
      }

Comment: its a function that is used for connecting and running the query

Comment: Wrapper functions like that often get in the way of safety and correctness. In this case you use the problematic `query` function instead of the proper `prepare`, `bind_param`, and `execute` approach. It's extremely important to use placeholder values instead of inlining (injecting) data into your query string. A single mistake where unescaped data gets in there can have catastrophic consequences.

Comment: SO WHAT ARE U REFERRING IS TO CHANGE THAT WRAPPER FUNCTION AND EACH TIME I PREPARE AND EXECUTE THE DIFFERENT SQL QUERY

Comment: Easy on the all caps, that's not cool.

Comment: What I'm saying is that wrapper function gets in the way and obscures what's happening. It's important for your SQL code to be clearly articulated so anyone reviewing it can verify it's being done correctly and without mistakes that could be huge liabilities, like SQL injection bugs.

Comment: how many minimum bits are required to avoid overflow during substraction of 2   n-bit nos  is it n-bit only or n+1 bit